# User defined function to calculate differences between two columns based on value provided by user

Tags: sql-server-2008, user-defined-functions, calculated-columns

I have four columns in my table:

- **Taxandotherexpenditurespercent**
- *NetAmount***
- ****Taxandotherexpendituremoney*****
- **Amount**

Now what I want is a user defined function in **netamount** column which calculates difference between **Amount** and according to the value supplied by user

i.e. Suppose the user supplies 25% as **Taxandotherexpenditurespercent** then **NetAmount** must be **amount**-***Taxandotherexpenditurespercent***

Similarly if the value supplies is 100 then **NetAmount** must be **Amount**-***Taxandotherexpendituremoney***.

I have tried googling it and everything but i can't find any satisfied explanation to user defined functions?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do. Ofcourse alter a bit to suit your requirements.

```
CREATE FUNCTION UDF_FindDifference (@OtherExpenditures VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @NetAmount INT

IF(CHARINDEX('%', @OtherExpenditures) > 0)
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @Amount INT

        SELECT @Amount = Taxandotherexpenditurespercent FROM yourTABLE

        SET @NetAmount = @Amount - REPLACE(@OtherExpenditures, '%', '')


    END
ELSE
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @Amount2 INT

        SELECT @Amount2 = Taxandotherexpendituremoney FROM yourTABLE

        SET @NetAmount = @Amount2 - @OtherExpenditures

    END 
RETURN @NetAmount
END
```

So here i am checking if the user input has `%` sign and based on this criteria i am doing the calculation.